# Can colex order be applied so sets of different sizes?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Suppose I have a subset $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{P}(n)$ for some $n$.

Are there extension of the notion of colexicographic order that apply to ordering of these sets of different sizes?

I have only ever seen a colexigraphic ordering applied to sets of the same sizes, but if one uses the definition $A<B$ iff $\text{max}\{A\triangle B\} \in B$ then it can apply to sets of different sizes too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The one extension I know about is the following (I borrowed it from [On the trace of finite sets](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(83)90038-9) by Peter Frankl):

$A < B$ iff $A \subset B$ or $\max(A \triangle B) \in B$.

One of the applications is [a theorem by Rudolf Ahlswede and Gyula O. H. Katona](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(77)90017-6) (which is a generalization/corollary of the Kruskal-Katona theorem). Define $L(n,m)$ as the first $m$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ in colexicographic order.

**Theorem.**
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a downward-closed (sometimes called hereditary) family of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $\left|\mathcal{F}\right| = m$.
Then for every monotone non-increasing function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
  \sum_{F \in \mathcal{F}} f(\left|F\right|) \ge \sum_{F \in L(n, m)} f(\left|F\right|).
$$